# Failed to render and update auto layout

Tags: swift, xcode, xib, ibdesignable, ibinspectable

I am using Xcode 13.4.1 in **Rosseta** mode on Macbook Pro (M1 chip) running macOS Monterey v12.0.

Basically, IBDesignable views are not getting updated in XIB and throwing weird errors.

All the details are in the screenshot attached.

[image]

Note: ***When I open Xcode in default mode (Rosetta options unchecked), everything works fine.***

Comment: This sounds like an Xcode bug. You can [file feedback with Apple](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/) or use a [Technical Support Incident](https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/) to get help from an Apple engineer. (You get 2 TSIs per year free with your developer account, and the TSI will be refunded if it turns out to be an Apple bug.)

Comment: I can imagine it is related to the "Architectures", please, click on your project, in the main window click on your project name unter "PROJECT", go to "Build Settings", select "All" and check the entry for "Architecture", do the same for your project under "TARGETS"

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps to solve the problem:

1. Go to File > Xcode Workspace Settings ---> click the Locations tab
2. Click the little right arrow beside "Derived data". This opens the Finder app at the location of the DerivedData folder.
   Go inside the DerivedData folder and delete the folder corresponding to your project.
3. Quit **Xcode** and re-open it.
4. Clean your project shift + command + k.
5. Build your project.
6. Open your storyboard.
   Go to Editor ---> Refresh All Views.